# Load all images from resource in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an offline application in Xamarin Forms, I'm currently saving images in specific projects (Android and iOS) and would like to load them all into a ListView. I tried using the following code:

```
IEnumerable <string> images = Directory.EnumerateFiles("Resources", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But I was unsuccessfully, could anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Resources are not files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateImagesFromResource(Func<FieldInfo, bool> filter)
{
    return typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetFields().Where(filter).Select(s => s.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do like this,i suggest you to save the images into **Assets** folder,and you could iterate the folder and filter with `.png`.

for example in **Android** :

```
List<System.IO.Stream> streamList = new List<System.IO.Stream>();
AssetManager assetManager = Assets;
string[] images = assetManager.List("");
for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
   {
     if (images[i].EndsWith(".png"))
       {
          using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assetManager.Open(images[i])))
             {
               streamList.Add(sr.BaseStream);
             }
       }
   }
```

Assets in android:

[image]

you could get the list of image stream by [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) or [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Comment: What would be your variable "Assets"?

Comment: @PedroPaulo it's a Resource file in android,you could put your  file,pictures,txt or other types files in it.see the screenshot above